# tabs in bootstrap modal autoswitches

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using tabs in bootstrap modal, the tabs shows well but the problem is, when i click on 'Section 2' tab, it immediately switches back to 'Section 1' tab. below is the code. any one who could help me enforce this using JavaScript or perhaps what could be the problem? i have searched with no success!

```
<div class="tabbable"> 
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe its because of the `active` word

Comment: PawCabelin, how can i solve  that programatically using jquery.am not an expert in this.your help highly appreciated.

Comment: I created a fiddle and its seems to work ok http://jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/KBRJy/

Comment: So when a tab is clicked does a postback occur? If it does then the selected tab will refresh back to *Section 1* because that's the default based on your markup

Comment: try the fiddle made by @ChrisMoutray it works fine.

Comment: @Chris, the postback still appears.how can i use jquery perhaps to remove the **active** class from Section 1 and asign it to section 2 and make sure content for section 2 appears

Comment: You must have some JavaScript you're not sharing because the markup you posted works fine. See this jsBin: http://jsbin.com/ifidot/1/edit

Comment: @vbruce Have you included bootstrap-tab.js file?

Comment: @chris, yes i have. am supposing that i have other jquery plugins (flot,knob,peity,calender and validate) that are conflicting,but i cant figure out which one!

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [Bootstrap help documentation on tabs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs) there is a requirement to include `bootstrap-tab.js` and without this the page will postback/not work correctly.

> **Requires jQuery plugin**
>
> All tabbable tabs are powered by our lightweight jQuery plugin. Read more about how to bring tabbable tabs to life on the JavaScript docs page.

Also see here > http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

So there are a couple of ways to get this

1. Include the **Togglable tabs** plugin when customizing your download http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html (see Section 2 - Select jQuery plugins)
2. Download the full package or link to a CDN eg `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js`

I think for testing you could also link here

```
`http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js`
```